# gradually migrate application from codeigniter to Laravel

Tags: codeigniter, laravel, migration

I have a quite large application written in Codeigniter 1.7.

It needs some significant enhancements and I have been evaluating Laravel 4 as the PHP framework.

I am trying to find out if anyone has successfully extended an existing Codeigniter application using Laravel so that some screens are Laravel and some are Codeigniter.

I imagine that authentication (currently using Ion Auth) and Session management (using mysql backend) would be two major hurdles to overcome.

If this is an option then I will explore in more detail as the amount of legacy code needing transferring is considerable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are completely different frameworks. Anything that you have written in standard PHP will work fine but anything that is CodeIgniter specific will need to be rewritten so that is uses the Laravel 4 functions/methods. It may be easier to move it all over in one go since CI 1.7 was never designed with namespaces or autoloading. Good luck

Comment: Pyrocms was built originally in codeigniter and is slowly transitioning to Laravel. https://www.pyrocms.com Its easy to use different frameworks and languages on one account, just use folders like if domain.com is picked up by codeigniter, domain.com/admin can be picked up by Laravel. that way you can build/improve your apps not just replace them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose in your Laravel routes file, create a route for every page you have written in CodeIgniter.  Route everything to the URL that CodeIgniter is expecting and as you complete portions in Laravel, change the routes to point to the correct ones Laravel expects as you go.

Before you do anything though, I'd get everything you need for authentication finished in Laravel, turn authentication off in CodeIgniter, and just let Laravel handle that in the routes.

Comment: Thanks @user1669496. I can't quite see how I can get Laravel routes to handle the authentication for the Codeigniter pages though.

I think I may need to get Laravel to authenticate the user in the (Ion Auth) Codeigniter security on log in.  Then use a different directory on the server for the Codeigniter pages.

Did you have another idea?

Comment: I was originally thinking you could turn your CI authentication off and handle all of it in your routes.php file in Laravel before you redirect.  Unfortunately I had not considered what would happen if they went directly to the CI path, which could circumvent the authentication.  Maybe if you set a session variable on authentication in Laravel and checked for that variable in CI's base class when you need to.